# Vertical aligning an image next to a textbox doesn't work in Chrome or Safari

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align an image link next to a textbox. Here's my markup:

```
<div style="height: 18px; overflow: hidden; padding: 5px 6px 6px 5px; width: 207px; background-color: #21235C">
    <input id="search" type="text" name="search" style="height: 18px; padding: 0; width: 182px; border: none;" />
    <a style="vertical-align: top;" href="#">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/0UZyz.png" alt="search" />
    </a>
</div>
```

This works fine in FF and IE. The image aligns correctly next to the textbox. But in Chrome and Safari, the textbox is pushed down.

Here it is in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tQUyW/

Any way to fix that?

Comment: "vertical-align" on inline elements acts completely differently than "vertical-align" on table cells. See [How (Not) to Vertically Center Content](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html), which applies to anything using the "vertical-align" property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Float the `a` element right, and remove `vertical-align: top` as noted by @animuson.

http://jsfiddle.net/fTadS/1